# disable propagation of css hover when nested

Tags: html, css

I have a container element that somewhere in its tree contains another element, whose visibility should be toggled when hovering over the container element. This works fine

```
.container .toggle {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.container:hover .toggle {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Problem is, when I nest two containers with separate `.toggle` elements both elements are visible when hovering over the parent container.
The easiest fix is to change add a `>` into the `:hover` css selector. That works fine as long as the `.toggle` element is a direct child of the `.container` element.

In my use case I cannot guarantee that this is the case, the number of elements between the `.container` and `.toggle` element must be variable.

My best guess was a CSS the selector `.container:hover *:not(.container) .toggle`
trying to select every child of a container, that is not a child of another container... sadly that is not working

Here's the fiddle: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F0N00I8GETY0

Any hints welcome, thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to stipulate the maximum nesting level, you can do this as follows.

```css
div { outline: red 1px solid; }

/* Hide toggle elts by default. */
.toggle { visibility: hidden; }

/* Show toggle elts whose container is hovered. */
.container:hover .toggle { visibility: visible; }

/* Unless there is a non-hovered container in between! */
.container:hover .container:not(:hover) .toggle { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  OUTSIDE CONTAINER
  <div class="toggle">OUTSIDE TOGGLE</div>
  <div class="container">
    INSIDE CONTAINER
    <div class="toggle">INSIDE TOGGLE</div>
</div>
```

To support three levels of nesting, you'd need a rule such as

```
.container:hover .container:hover .container:not(:hover) .toggle { visibility: hidden; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution works great, as far as I can tell it also works if I add more nesting levels (see http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F0OHUDWMUUVZ), tested in Firefox and Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest thing I can think of is to toggle the visibility of the inner `.toggle` elements to `hidden` when toggling the parent `.toggle` element.

```
.container .toggle {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.container:hover .toggle {
    visibility: visible;
}
.container:hover .toggle .toggle {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

but then again this code wont allow you to toggle the nested `.toggle` elements' visibility, so you must add to the code above:

```
.toggle:hover .toggle {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

but this only works as intended when you only have two nested `.toggle` elements. And I'm afraid to say if you wanna toggle more nested elements you need to use js.

Comment: Can't you just add more rules for each additional level of nesting you want to support?

Comment: of course you can, but if the number of nesting is unlimited or better say more than a few, it would be really messy and it would be a better idea to use js

Answer (score 0):

If container is always in div, something like this could work

```
.container:hover div:not(.container) .toggle, .container .container:hover .toggle, .container:hover > .toggle {
 visibility: visible;
}
```